# Get only "valid" points in 2D interpolation of cloud point using Scipy/Numpy

Tags: 3d, numpy, scipy, smoothing

I have a cloud point obtained from photogrammetry from a person's back. I'm trying to interpolate it to get a regular grid, and for that I'm using `scipy.interpolate` with good results so far. The problem is: the function I'm using (`scipy.interpolate.griddata`) uses the convex hull of the cloudpoint in the plane x,y, thus giving as result some values that don't exist in the original surface, which has a concave perimeter.

The following illustration shows the original cloudpoint at the left (what is displayed as horizontal lines is actually a dense line-shaped cloud of points), the result that `griddata` gives me in the middle, and the result I would like to get at the right -- kind of the "shadow" of the cloudpoint on the x,y plane, where non-existing points in the original surface would be zeros or Nans.

[image]

I know I could remove the Z coordinate on the cloudpoint and check each grid position for proximity, but this is so brute-force, and I believe this should be a common problem on point-cloud applications.
Another possibility could be some numpy operation to perform over the point-cloud, finding a numpy mask or boolean 2D-array to "apply" over the result from `griddata`, but I didn't find any (these operations are a bit beyond my Numpy/Scipy knowledge).

Any suggestion?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suitable masks can be constructed fast using `KDTree`. The interpolation algorithm used by griddata does not have a notion of "valid" points, so you need to adjust your data either before or after the interpolation.

Before:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some input data
t = 1.2*np.pi*np.random.rand(3000)
r = 1 + np.random.rand(t.size)
x = r*np.cos(t)
y = r*np.sin(t)
z = x**2 - y**2

# -- Way 1: seed input with nan

def excluding_mesh(x, y, nx=30, ny=30):
    """
    Construct a grid of points, that are some distance away from points (x, 
    """

    dx = x.ptp() / nx
    dy = y.ptp() / ny

    xp, yp = np.mgrid[x.min()-2*dx:x.max()+2*dx:(nx+2)*1j,
                      y.min()-2*dy:y.max()+2*dy:(ny+2)*1j]
    xp = xp.ravel()
    yp = yp.ravel()

    # Use KDTree to answer the question: "which point of set (x,y) is the
    # nearest neighbors of those in (xp, yp)"
    tree = KDTree(np.c_[x, y])
    dist, j = tree.query(np.c_[xp, yp], k=1)

    # Select points sufficiently far away
    m = (dist > np.hypot(dx, dy))
    return xp[m], yp[m]

# Prepare fake data points
xp, yp = excluding_mesh(x, y, nx=35, ny=35)
zp = np.nan + np.zeros_like(xp)

# Grid the data plus fake data points
xi, yi = np.ogrid[-3:3:350j, -3:3:350j]
zi = griddata((np.r_[x,xp], np.r_[y,yp]), np.r_[z, zp], (xi, yi),
              method='linear')
plt.imshow(zi)
plt.show()
```

The idea is to "seed" the input data with fake data points containing `nan` values. When using linear interpolation, these will blot out areas of the image that have no actual data points nearby.

You can also blot out invalid data after the interpolation:

```
# -- Way 2: blot out afterward

xi, yi = np.mgrid[-3:3:350j, -3:3:350j]
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi))

tree = KDTree(np.c_[x, y])
dist, _ = tree.query(np.c_[xi.ravel(), yi.ravel()], k=1)
dist = dist.reshape(xi.shape)
zi[dist > 0.1] = np.nan

plt.imshow(zi)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I've been busy, but your answer as I read now (having already scratched my head a lot) makes a lot of sense. In the end, I am using KDtree to perform the interpolation for each of the grid points, doing this: I create a grid of NaN; I test each grid node, with kdtree, for presence of vicinity (ignoring z coordinate of cloudpoint); If there is vicinity, interpolate using Rbf (in the end, griddata was not so good for this problem), and assign the result to the corresponding node of the output.