# How do I create a binary mask on a square grid from a 2D cloud of points in Python?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, points

I have a the X and Y coordinates of a 2D cloud of points that I want to map onto a 2D uniform grid with a resolution of `imageResolution` of initially all zeros. I want all pixels in the grid which overlay the 2D cloud of points to contain ones, to produce a binary image.

Please note, there are a very large number of points both in my 2D cloud of points and in the uniform grid, and so loops are not an effective solution here.

I have looked at convex hulls but my points are not necessarily in a convex set.

I have tried this following code, but its not giving me the correct binary map, since its only assigning 1s to the nearest grid points closest to the points in the point cloud (see image below):

```
X = points[:,0] #1D array of X coordinates
Y = points[:,1] #1D array of Y coordinates

imageResolution = 256
xVec = np.linspace(0,800,imageResolution)
yVec = xVec

def find_index(x,y):
    xi=np.searchsorted(xVec,x)
    yi=np.searchsorted(yVec,y)
    return xi,yi

xIndex, yIndex = find_index(X,Y)

binaryMap = np.zeros((imageResolution,imageResolution))

binaryMap[xIndex,yIndex] = 1

fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(binaryMap, cmap='jet')
plt.colorbar()
```

Please see this image which shows my 2D cloud of points, the desired binary map I want, and the current binary map I am getting from the code above. Please note the red pixels are difficult to see in the last image.

[image: Images describing this problem]

How do I create a binary mask on a square grid from a 2D cloud of points in Python?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10560275/6386471

Comment: Hi @user6386471, griddata uses the concept of a convex hull, while my data points are not necessarily in a convex set. I also have non convex data points

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER :: Untested suggestion**

If I've understood correctly, rather than mark an individual pixel with `1`, you should be marking a neighborhood of pixels.

You could try inserting the following lines just before `binaryMap[xIndex,yIndex] = 1`:

```
DELTA_UPPER=2                                # Param. Needs fine-tuning
delta = np.arange(DELTA_UPPER).reshape(-1,1)
xIndex = xIndex + delta
xIndex [xIndex >= imageResolution] = imageResolution-1
yIndex = yIndex + delta
yIndex [yIndex >= imageResolution] = imageResolution-1

x_many, y_many = np.broadcast_arrays (xIndex[:,None], yIndex)

xIndex = x_many.reshape(-1)
yIndex = y_many.reshape(-1)
```

**Note:**

`DELTA_UPPER` is a parameter that you will have to fine-tune by playing around with. (Maybe start with `DELTA_UPPER=3`)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. If I mark a neighbourhood of pixels, the border of the shape will not be represented correctly on the binary map

Comment: @InternetUser0947  Quote: "I have tried this following code, but its not giving me the correct binary map, since its only assigning 1s to the nearest grid points closest to the points in the point cloud". To me, this sounded like the crux of your requirement. (I interpreted that as meaning that the precision of the plotting was causing things to be less visible). Hence I posted this solution. Could you please re-clarify what is it that is wrong in the current output amd what is your expectation in the output. Thanks.

Comment: @InternetUser0947 -- If you were looking for a more accurate way of plotting, perhaps you could have tried `binaryMap[X,Y] = 1` instead of `binaryMap[xIndex,yIndex] = 1` (as you have already defined `X = points[:,0]` and `Y = points[:,1]`). This assumes that the values in `points` are strictly integers that are in `range(imageResolution)`. What was the need for the `find_index()` function? Am I missing something?

Comment: please see the image I posed along with my question. In particular, please look at the output I want, compared with the current output. I essentially want all ones everywhere in the domain where the 2D cloud of points are, and zeros everywhere else.

Regarding your second point, X and Y are points which 1) are not integers and 2) do not coincide with the 2D grid points.

Comment: Please see my second answer posted just now. It rounds off the values in `X` and `Y` and ensures that they can safely be used as indexes into `binaryMap`. Pls let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED CODE**

Based on further clarifications, posting this second answer, to better index the `binaryMap`, given that `points` contains floats.

```
imageResoluton = 256
MAX_X = # Fill in here the max x value ever possible in `points`
MIN_X = # Fill in here the min x value ever possible in `points`
MAX_Y = # Fill in here the max y value ever possible in `points`
MIN_Y = # Fill in here the min y value ever possible in `points`

SCALE_FAC = imageResolution / max(MAX_X-MIN_X, MAX_Y-MIN_Y)

X = np.around(SCALE_FAC * points[:,0]).astype(np.int64)
Y = np.around(SCALE_FAC * points[:,1]).astype(np.int64)
X [X >= imageResolution] = imageResolution-1
Y [Y >= imageResolution] = imageResolution-1

binaryMap[X, Y] = 1
```

(There's no need for `find_index()`)

Comment: Hello, this doesn't work. Because X and Y are independent point cloud coordinates. They do not coincide with the uniform grid. They are just the x-coordinates and y-coordinates of a the scatter of points which make up the shape.

Comment: Is there any defined max and min range for the values in `points` ? Some range that will never be exceeded? If so, you could then find the scaling factor to scale all the x and y values of `points`, down to the scale of the 256x256 grid

Comment: @InternetUser0947 -- I have edited this answer to show how the scaling logic would look like. Let me know if this can work

Comment: I tried this solution just now and I can confirm it still doesn't work. Its producing an output which looks similar to the third image, where only few points take the value of 1. While I would like an image like the 2nd picture.

Comment: This probably means that the cloud is too sparse to see (the points are too far apart. It means, you may have to mark neighborhoods of pixels rather than individual pixels. Could you tell me how many points do you have in `points` ?

Comment: One quick way to test whether this is due to sparseness -- run this solution with a smaller value of `imageResolution` (such as 128x128). The cloud points would now be scaled down more than before, and would get crowded into a smaller grid. The cloud might become more visible then.

Comment: I just tried it with 128*128 and 64*64 and still get the same result. I'm not too keen on this approach anyway since the border would not be correct. Ideally the border should be sharp like the 2nd image I showed